# Text appears fine on interface builder and blurry on simulator and non retina displays

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uitextview, retina-display

I created text views non programmatically in the interface builder of Xcode. The text appears clear on interface builder but blurry in the non retina simulator and on iPads without retina displays. I am using Helvetica Neue and Bold versions about the font. Both the bold and regular versions of the font appear fuzzy on non retina displays but clear on retina displays. How can I keep the text readable on both displays?

Comment: Are you sure its not the fact that non-retina displays have a lower resolution and hence will not be as clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this error make sure the sizes of your views are divisible by 4.

Comment: As silly as it sounds, I tried it out and it didn't work. My view is 224 width x 48 height and still looks wrong.